# View pager inside recycler view

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

how create view pager with  recycler view I mean " each element in recycler view have view pager"   like Google podcast app
Thanks in advance [image]![Like this ]

Comment: i think u probably need nested recycleView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horizontal RecyclerView in Vertical RecyclerView like Google Play Store

take a look here:https://android-pratap.blogspot.com/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html